# Pulsate effect for the heart shape css3

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

i'm trying to implement the pulsate effect similar to the following

[pulsate animation](https://codepen.io/koltong/pen/JjKPwgg)

since the above code works well only for circle or square shapes, is there any way we can achieve the same effect for the svg heart shape?

```
<svg class="heart" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewbox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M8.612,2.347L8,2.997l-0.612-0.65c-1.69-1.795-4.43-1.795-6.12,0c-1.69,1.795-1.69,4.706,0,6.502l0.612,0.65L8,16  l6.12-6.502l0.612-0.65c1.69-1.795,1.69-4.706,0-6.502C13.042,0.551,10.302,0.551,8.612,2.347z" fill="#fff" transform="scale( 0.954929658551372 )"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Heart with Pulse Animation : https://youtu.be/Jq4diUd10Zs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to animate the stroke width.

```css
svg {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
  overflow: visible;
}

use {
  stroke: red;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: pulsing 1000ms ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulsing {
  from {
    opacity: 0.5;
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    stroke-width: 12px;
  }
}

.element {
  animation: pulsing 1000ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<svg class="heart" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
  <use xlink:href="#shape"/>
  <path id="shape" d="M8.612,2.347L8,2.997l-0.612-0.65c-1.69-1.795-4.43-1.795-6.12,0c-1.69,1.795-1.69,4.706,0,6.502l0.612,0.65L8,16  l6.12-6.502l0.612-0.65c1.69-1.795,1.69-4.706,0-6.502C13.042,0.551,10.302,0.551,8.612,2.347z" fill="#f00" transform="scale( 0.954929658551372 )"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest fix would be to swap `box-shadow` for `filter: drop-shadow`. This'll work for arbitrary shapes.

This solution isn't really ideal, though; `box-shadow` / `drop-shadow` are expensive to animate. Instead, you can use `transform: scale` and `opacity`, something like:

```
@keyframes pulsing {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(3);
  }
}

.element {
  animation: pulsing 1000ms ease-out;
}
```